# Drawing an unfolded recurrent neural network

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am trying to create an "unfolded" version of this diagram made with tikz:

[image]

This was made with the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit, arrows.meta}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

    \usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

    \graphicspath{ {images/} }

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

    \def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);

\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-1) to [out=90,in=180,loop,looseness=8.8] (hidden-1);
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-2) to [out=-90,in=180,loop,looseness=8.8] (hidden-2);

\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-1) to [out=180,in=180,loop,looseness=2.8] (hidden-2);
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-2) to [out=180,in=180,loop,looseness=1.8] (hidden-1);


\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Ouput}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Now I am trying to do something like this but can't really figure out how to modify my code so that I will have Three networks next to each other:

[image]

I looked at the question in the following link, but it is not quite the same as what I am trying to do: [How to Draw Recurrent Neural Network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328733/how-to-draw-recurrent-neural-network)

So can my code be modified for me to do this? Do you Think it would be possible to rotate the networks -90 degrees so that they fit an A4 page better?

Comment: That code alone doesn't produce the image you show, the circles are missing. I guess the `neuron` stuff is responsible for that. Can you turn your snippet into a complete example?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you for telling me that, I have now updated the code in the question so that it should be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method is to add another `\foreach` loop, that repeats everything you have done three times. Note that the nodes are positioned at e.g. `(0+\X,2.5-\y)`, where `\X` is the loop variable for the new, outer loop. There are some adjustments to node names, to accommodate three instances of the same.

Some adjustments of the newly added arrows (final `\foreach` loop) might be in order.

To rotate it you could just swap x and y coordinates everywhere. Below, I instead swapped the unit vectors.

I commented out some unused, and invisible, nodes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % swap the unit vectors
   x={(0,-1cm)},
   y={(1.5cm,0)},
   >=stealth,
   ]
\foreach [count=\xx] \X in {0,6.5,13}{
\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m-\xx) at (0+\X,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m-\xx) at (2+\X,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m-\xx) at (4+\X,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i-\xx) -- ++(-1,0);
%    node [above, midway] {};

%\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
%  \node [above] at (hidden-\i-\xx.north) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i-\xx) -- ++(1,0);
%    node [above, midway] {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i-\xx) -- (hidden-\j-\xx);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i-\xx) -- (output-\j-\xx);

\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-1-\xx) to [out=0,in=90,loop,looseness=8.8] (hidden-1-\xx);
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-2-\xx) to [out=180,in=90,loop,looseness=8.8] (hidden-2-\xx);

\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-1-\xx) to [out=90,in=90,loop,looseness=1.7] (hidden-2-\xx);
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-2-\xx) to [out=90,in=90,loop,looseness=1] (hidden-1-\xx);


\foreach \l/\txt [count=\x from 0] in {Input/input, Hidden/hidden, Output/output}
  \node [align=center] at (\txt-1-\xx-|+0,3) {\l \\ layer};
}% end of outer foreach


\foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] \i in {1,2}
{
  \draw [red] (hidden-1-\i) to[bend left] (hidden-1-\j);
  \draw [red] (hidden-1-\i) to[bend left] (hidden-2-\j);
  \draw [red] (hidden-2-\i) to[bend right] (hidden-1-\j);
  \draw [red] (hidden-2-\i) to[bend right] (hidden-2-\j);


}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Next to each other

This is still wider than the textblock though.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=7mm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % swap the unit vectors
   x={(0,-1cm)},
   y={(1.1cm,0)},
   >=stealth,
   ]
\foreach [count=\xx] \X in {0,4,8}{
\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m-\xx) at (0,2.5-\y+\X) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m-\xx) at (2,2-\y*1.25+\X) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m-\xx) at (4,2-\y*1.25+\X) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i-\xx) -- ++(-1,0);
%    node [above, midway] {};

%\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
%  \node [above] at (hidden-\i-\xx.north) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i-\xx) -- ++(1,0);
%    node [above, midway] {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i-\xx) -- (hidden-\j-\xx);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i-\xx) -- (output-\j-\xx);

\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-1-\xx) to [out=0,in=90,loop,looseness=8.8] (hidden-1-\xx);
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-2-\xx) to [out=180,in=90,loop,looseness=8.8] (hidden-2-\xx);

\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-1-\xx) to [out=90,in=90,loop,looseness=1.7] (hidden-2-\xx);
\draw[->,shorten >=1pt] (hidden-2-\xx) to [out=90,in=90,loop,looseness=1] (hidden-1-\xx);

}% end of outer foreach

\foreach \l/\txt [count=\x from 0] in {Input/input, Hidden/hidden, Output/output}
  \node [align=center] at (\txt-1-\xx-|0,-2.5) {\l \\ layer};

\foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] \i in {1,2}
{
  \draw [red,->] (hidden-1-\i) to[bend left] (hidden-1-\j);
  \draw [red,->] (hidden-1-\i) to[bend left] (hidden-2-\j);
  \draw [red,->] (hidden-2-\i) to[bend right] (hidden-1-\j);
  \draw [red,->] (hidden-2-\i) to[bend right] (hidden-2-\j);


}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wait, I messed up some of those arrows. You can probably fix it yourself, but I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: I can't Believe you figured that out so fast, thanks alot! I will study your example. Using the foreach like you did, would it possible to align them next to each other (still rotated separately)?

Comment: @StephenJohnson Probably just add `+\X` to the y-coordinate instead of the x-coordinate, will edit in a bit.

Comment: @StephenJohnson See edited answer.

Comment: It works perfectly fine! I am very thankful. The textblock width was solved by difining Another style for the neuron, which I called small neuron, with only minimum size of 0.5 cm. Thank you alot again!